# Powershell: Is it bad to omit an 'else' if I don't need it?

Tags: powershell

I have a basic question about `if/else` query in Powershell.

With `if` I check a condition. In many cases I don't need an `else` to run my Code. The code works the same way. But isn't this unclean? What is best practice?

In other words: is it bad to omit an `else` if I don't need it after an `if`?

**The obviously correct way:**

```
$foo = "bar"

    if (!$foo) {
           Write-Warning "'bar' is missing!" -WarningAction -Continue
    }
    else {
    
        # Proceed with my Code ...
    }
```

**The lazy way:**

```
$foo = "bar"

    if (!$foo) {
           Write-Warning "'bar' is missing!" -WarningAction -Continue
    }

    # Proceed with my Code ...
```

Comment: no, everybody does that. No one writes `else` unnecessarily

Comment: I don't do it either. I'm just curious if this is considered messy programming. Just because many people cheat on taxes doesn't make it right :-)

Comment: No, it is not considered messy programming or bad style. The opposite is the case ... why having unnecessary code distracting you when you want to read and understand the code?  ;-)

Comment: definitely many people do use it, but typically only when there are some code that'll be implemented later, so there are just some comments inside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, but.**

In your example, the "correct" and "lazy" versions will not behave in identical a way.

The "lazy" one has a conditional block for the first part, but the rest is always executed.

The "correct" part has two conditional blocks. The code is executed either in the `if` branch, or in the `else` branch.

The difference is quite critical. Assume you want to ask user if deleting a bunch of files is OK and then doing it. Consider the difference carefully:

```
# "Lazy" version
if($are_you_sure) {
    write-output "OK, deleting all your files"
}
# Oops!
Delete-My-Files --force


# "Correct" version    
if($are_you_sure) {
    write-output "OK, deleting all your files"
    Delete-My-Files --force
} else {
    write-output "Skipping over file deletion"
}
```

On the other hand, it's perfectly OK to skip the `else{}` branch iff you are going to run rest of the code regardless what the `if` branch does.